# C++ library for lat/long to screen coordinates

Tags: library, c++, gis

I am looking for a C++ library that will allow me to draw a map from a series of WGS84 lat/long geospatial points onto a canvas. Specifically, a wxPanel or perhaps wxGLCanvas, but I don't think the canvas implementation is important.

This is for a very small FOSS project and I would like re-use any [open-source] code as much as possible.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but maybe you should ask the OpenStreetMaps.org people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An old question, but you should look at the Proj.4 library. It is actually C. Written by the USGS, virtually all map projection libraries encapsulate this. It is so widespread that map projections are often specified using the proj.4 command line parameters (as well as a library, it has a command line tool).

Looks like Proj.4 has now moved on from its USGS origins and is now known as "PROJ" (and upto v6). It can be found here:

https://proj.org/

(you will need to decide on the map projection to use. Mercator is popular but it will depend on your application - imho Mercator is over used!)